# Using Kindle app on iPad how to search my notes

Tags: ipad, search, ipados, kindle

Kindle service allows us to make notes as we read text and these notes synchronize to all kindle apps. Specifically I want to search MY notes, across all books in my kindle app or in 1 collection.

In testing this, no note text is found, despite searching for a very specific phrase I entered into a note.

Is this a feature on kindle for iPad app?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to further your explanation of the problem?

Comment: I’d love to attach a screenshot but that’s a harder issue (with stackexchange) than the original question. 

That said, I don’t think a screenshot would help anyway, I put very unique note attached to a word in a book. The note has an exact date on it and the word test note I can’t find the date or the words test note when I search.

When searching I’m searching everything on my iPad with Kindle not just one book.
Hopefully that gives you enough information to try to help me. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, I fear I won't be able to assist you further in your inquiry as I don't use the Kindle app and have actually no idea on how to operate to solve your issue. Apologies and good luck.

Comment: Thanks. By any chance do you know if either a regular Kindle app or Kindle scribe can search user added notes, across all books or all books in a collection? I'm giving up using the Kindle app, wondering if Kindle or Kindle Scribe will serve my needs. Who needs color anyways?